# latex knitr chunk echo=FALSE disrupts par() setting

Tags: knitr

I'm new to latex and knitr and have an issue with the output from an R chunk when I use echo=FALSE. The .Rnw code below works as expected i.e. the output has

```
    1. some code
    2. a block of figures arranged 2 x 3
    3. some more code
    4. a block of figures arranged 2 x 3
```

However changing the chunk opening to eliminate the code block from the output

`<<bghist2_mas_rma, fig.height=4, fig.width=6, echo=FALSE>>=`

not only removes the code from output (good) but also over-rides the par() setting such that the two figures (each of 2 x 3) are placed adjacent on the page, with most of the second falling off the edge.

Other than simply leaving the code in the output how could I get around this?

thanks

B

```
\newpage
<<bghist2_mas_rma, fig.height=4, fig.width=6, echo=TRUE>>=
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in 1:6){
    hist(bg.mas[,i], xlab="", las=1,
    main=paste(sep="", "bg.mas[, ",  i, "]"),
    xlim=c(-100, 300), breaks=10000)
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in 1:6){
    hist(bg.rma[,i], xlab="", las=1,
    main=paste(sep="", "bg.rma[, ",  i, "]"),
    xlim=c(-100, 300), breaks=10000)
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
@
```

Comment: besides the answer below, I guess you can also use the chunk option `fig.align='center'` so that the two figures are written into two paragraphs and will no longer sit side by side.

Comment: Thanks Yihui, that's also a useful tip for the future. As it is, I've decided to make each chunk a single-delivery entity, so this issue should no longer arise.  May I say I like knitr a lot; it's early days in may learning curve for R + RStudio + latex etc but I'm impressed with what can be  acheived & look forward to learning more. best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to split them into separate chunks:

```
<<bghist2_mas_rma, fig.height=4, fig.width=6, echo=FALSE>>=
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in 1:6){
    hist(bg.mas[,i], xlab="", las=1,
    main=paste(sep="", "bg.mas[, ",  i, "]"),
    xlim=c(-100, 300), breaks=10000)
}
@

<<bghist2_mas_rma_2, fig.height=4, fig.width=6, echo=FALSE>>=
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in 1:6){
    hist(bg.rma[,i], xlab="", las=1,
    main=paste(sep="", "bg.rma[, ",  i, "]"),
    xlim=c(-100, 300), breaks=10000)
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
@
```